# VirtualBox: connection reset by peer for NATted communications

Tags: virtualbox, macos-sierra

I'm on macOS Sierra, using VirtualBox 5.0.28 r111378, and my Ubuntu VMs frequently get `connection reset by peer` errors when making outbound HTTP calls via the NAT interface.

My use case often (but no exclusively) involves HTTP calls between the two; if I add an interface on the same virtual network then I don't get the issue. All the while they're using the NAT interface though, I get these very frequent connection resets. Updating the VMs I'm running doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with VirtualBox 5.1.8 running on macOS ElCapitan as Host OS. Guest OS was Ubuntu 14.04. On https connections I got intermittent connection reset by peer errors. I could overcome the situation by switching from NAT to NAT Network in the settings for the network adapter of my VM.